# How to delete a file with incorrect name?

Tags: windows, ntfs, hard-drive

Some application created several files with completely incorrect names in NTFS HDD because of incorrect input data. These files have lots of unrecognizable symbols including Unicode control characters and other "nice" things in their names, and they don't want to be deleted via common Windows 10 x64 Explorer method (with the "Element not found." error). I also tried to use CMD, but it doesn't work too, as mush as Unlocker and LockHunter don't, even with delating during restart function.

Comment: In CMD call `dir /x` to get the "short name" and try deletion with this name from CMD.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the <kbd>TAB</kbd> button while trying to select the file while working in commandline (<kbd>TAB</kbd> shows you the name of a file, as it can be used in commandline commands, `dir` or `del`).

Try this:

```
Prompt>DIR <TAB> <TAB> <TAB>
```

You should see:

```
Prompt>DIR first_file
Prompt>DIR second_file
Prompt>DIR third_file
```

When working with the Windows explorer, there should be no issue at all.

Comment: Thanks! Well, for real, it didn't work for deleting these files, but it perfectly deleted the whole directory, so it helped me.